# DAX Running total measure - from start of financial year until end of current month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Measure values keep going from the start of the financial year selected in page filter, to the end of the financial year selected in page filter. I need it to go from the start of the financial year selected in page filter, to the end of the current month. My measure is:

```
YTD Sales = 
    CALCULATE (
        sum(Revenue[Amount]), 
        DATESYTD(ForecastSalesDate[CalendarDate],"31/10")
    )
```

When I select financial year 2020 in page filter, I want it to show from 01/11/2019 upto 30/04/2020 (today is 16/04/2020), but it keeps going to 31/10/2020 (the financial year end):

[image]

What I am trying to get is:

[image]

The data model is:

[image]

Can anyone advise further?

Cheers for all help

Comment: Why not just add a 'Relative Date' filter at page/visual level?

Comment: Not sure why that would change anything? I already have a date filter at Page level, and its for financial year. Relative dates are for calendar years

Comment: You can add a relative date filter to exclude any data not in the past n calendar months, which would prevent your visual from displaying dates beyond 30/04 until May begins.

Comment: As an aside, that data model looks quite difficult to interpret. I'd suggest dragging your tables around so that they flow in the direction of one to many, or vice versa.

Comment: Also you seem to have two date dimension tables, I'd recommend merging these. In some data models it's necessary to have multiple, but not in yours as far as I can see.

Comment: I need two date dimensions as I have facts in different granularities - Revenue is on Date level, Targets are on Month level. Dont see how I can make it work otherwise?

Comment: You can bring the month level data into the date level dimension. The combined table can be used to slice both fact tables.

Comment: Relative filter for past 12 calendar months only goes to end of March, is there a way to include April in there too?

Comment: With date tables - are you suggesting moving the Month Target facts, into the Dates dimension table? Not sure how that works? One is facts, one is dimensions? and they are on different granularities, the Targets doesnt contain dates, only months in a text format of yyyy-mm

Comment: Not quite. I'm suggesting you keep two facts (Revenue, Targets) but keep only one date dimension table. Your date dim can hold day level and month level granularity at the same time, you don't need two dims for that. I'd also suggest not storing dates as text!

Comment: If I do that, then I cant join Targets to the Date table, as I would have a many to many relationship. Targets table contains targets per month per salesperson. Date table would contains multiple values for each month. So it wouldnt work?

Comment: You could store the target months as dates like (01, month, year) and link them to the date column in your date dim, retaining the ability to summarise at month level. That said, I wouldn't bother at this point. As for your original issue, if the relative filter doesn't work, you could add a condition to your measure to return `BLANK()` when the date context is later than `TODAY()`

Comment: This works - stored target months as dates and removed the extra Dates dim table. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Changed Target months to dates in format 01/mm/yyyy.
Removed second Dates dim table.
Added a new column to the remaining Dates dim table - MONTH(Calendardate - TODAY()). Then added this column into page filter, to be greater than or equal to 0